# Exceptions is not processed very well when a release buid is generated in React Native in Android

Tags: java, android, react-native

The problem is very simple, I have a part in my React Native project where I throw an Error, for example:

```
...
throw new Error('Example error');
...
```

When I normally execute `npx react-native run-android` to develop and debug I see the error correctly but when is in release mode `npx react-native run-android --variant=release` the error becomes weird.

Something like:

```
{
 "name": "v",
 "line": 1231,
 "column": 331,
 "sourceURL": "index.android.bundle"
}
```

Seems like if in the compilation to the Android .apk, something goes wrong with the errors.

Some clue for this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code gets transpiled, optimized, and minified in release builds. That's why they run faster than debug builds. The tradeoff is this, that the code becomes obfuscated to humans. If you want more details in your release builds, it's best to be more explicit with your errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abe I realized about it, the point is, how to avoid errors are raised this way? There is any way to keep the error with sense after all this process?

Comment: There are definitely ways - but they are difficult enough that you can charge for the service. Sentry is an example of a company with a React Native library that logs errors with improved readability and metrics. The easiest alternative is to be very explicit with logging and error messages - you can still get console logs from release builds, and that can help show your flow.

Comment: I've seen a few related posts talking about mapping react-native error to source from minified files, but I don't find a good approach without installing any third-party library.